# HTML & php buttons custom display information

Tags: php, html, button

I have a task list.

Initially I display all of them. I want to create 2 buttons s.t. one displays the tasks ordered by date, and the other displays the tasks that have passed.

How can I do this? I don't know how to make a button to do anything else than submit.
I was thinking about redirecting to another "page" but I'm not sure it is efficient.

```
<button type="button" name = 'display1' value="orderedDisplay">Order by date</button>
<button type="button" name = 'display2' value="passedTasks">Passed tasks</button>
```

or

```
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <a href="orderedbydate.php">Order by date</a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <a href="pastevents.php">Display past events</a>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

But I don't know how to "catch" the event of clicking with "button"type button.

Comment: just make an <a> tag and and when you click on it it execute your php script

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: have a look on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: this is also worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link. please try to do some research before  asking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a button doing something, you need some JavaScript, executing that "something":

```
<input type="button" name='display1' 
       onclick="callOrderByDate()" value="Order by date"/>


....
<script type="text/javascript">
   function callOrderByDate()
   {
        alert("I'm not ging to write the entire code here...");
   }
 ...
 </script>
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/e9h7u2bt/)